# PayPal integration with ionic hybrid mobile app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in ionic,I try a PayPal integration in my app but i have no any success in it.

If any one knows can please describe a steps wise integration of PayPal in ionic mobile app.

Comment: Please check "How to Ask questions" on Stack Overflow. Also, Google: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/can-we-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-with-ionic/32956

Answer (score 0):

I integrate it .. but it's not simple ...
I've used this :

```
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin
```